# Can NVIC enable interupt after CPSID i is execute

Tags: embedded, stm32

```
__disable_irq();
  // Setting timer 1
  ...
  NVIC_SetPriority (TIM1_UP_IRQn, 1);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ (TIM1_UP_IRQn);
  // do something
  ...
__enable_irq();
```

Can Timer 1 interrupt occur after NVIC_EnableIRQ (TIM1_UP_IRQn) is execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use ASM at all. CMSIS is has handy functions.

```
    __disable_irq();
    __enable_irq();
```

```
NVIC_EnableIRQ (TIM1_UP_IRQn);
```

Does not enable interrupts only enables particular interrupt source

Comment: Thank you for answer me @P__J__
So, Timer 1 can interrup while __disable_irq(); ?

Comment: No it will not.